# How to indent a paragraph so that it aligns horizontally with above list items

Tags: html, css, alignment, indentation

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```css
:root {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: min(100%, 1000px);
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  counter-increment: section;
}

p {
  /*
  How do this need to be formulated so that the paragraph starts at
  exactly the same horizontal position as the text of the list items?
  */
  margin-left: 2em;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(section) ".";
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indentation Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>An awesome title</h1>
    <h2>1. A section</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>An entry</li>
      <li>Another entry</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Another section</h2>
    <p>This paragraph should have the same indentation as the above list elements</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to horizontally align the paragraph with the list elements above it so that it starts at *exactly* the same location as the text of the list element. Just the text of the list items and the text of the paragraph should align, i.e. as shown in the below picture:

[image: The indentation of the paragraph]

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unordered list (`ol`'s) have a default `padding-inline-start: 40px;`. Meaning each child `li` is starting indented at `40px`. So if you want your `p` to start where the `li`'s start, I would add that same style.

You can adjust this `padding-inline-start` based on where you want your paragraph to start. However, `40px` will get you right where your list items start.

```css
:root {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: min(100%, 1000px);
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  counter-increment: section;
}

p {
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(section) ".";
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indentation Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>An awesome title</h1>
    <h2>1. A section</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>An entry</li>
      <li>Another entry</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Another section</h2>
    <p>This paragraph should have the same indentation as the above list elements</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is that `padding-inline-start: 40px;` defined in the specification somewhere? I just want to be sure that I can rely on that to be the case for all web browsers.

Comment: @ackh Yes, it is the default style for all browsers. You can see it here while in your dev tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dlS0.png. You can also read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists).

Answer (score 1):

check out the padding on the ol tag and then add margin-left:40px to the p tag

```css
:root {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: min(100%, 1000px);
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  counter-increment: section;
}

p {
  /*
  How do this need to be formulated so that the paragraph starts at
  exactly the same horizontal position as the text of the list items?
  */
  margin-left: 40px;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(section) ".";
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indentation Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>An awesome title</h1>
    <h2>1. A section</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>An entry</li>
      <li>Another entry</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Another section</h2>
    <p>This paragraph should have the same indentation as the above list elements</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: min(100%, 1000px);
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  counter-increment: section;
}

p {
  /*
  How do this need to be formulated so that the paragraph starts at
  exactly the same horizontal position as the text of the list items?
  */
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(section) ".";
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indentation Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>An awesome title</h1>
    <h2>1. A section</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>An entry</li>
      <li>Another entry</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>2. Another section</h2>
    <p>This paragraph should have the same indentation as the above list elements</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```